# Laravel: href with route in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, href

I'm trying to create `href` with route laravel. This route contains a parameter, but it always returns *Error 404*. I don´t know what I´m doing wrong.

I know that my question is very easy, I´m searching in Google for this, but I think that I'm doing well on my route.

My route:

```
/** SHOW EVENT INFO */
Route::get('event/{url}', 'Web\EventController@showEvent');
```

My href in `file.js`:

```
<a target="_blank" id="button-event-read" href="'+config.url.base_url+'event/'+eventUrl+'" class="btn color2-bg float-btn">Leer más.<i class="fal fa-angle-right"></i></a>
```

If I click in href, it goes to the correct route but ends up showing *Error 404*.

My controller:

```
public function showEvent($url){
        echo "here";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get Host url in variable

```
var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;
```

and then use it in href like this.

```
<a target="_blank" id="button-event-read" href="'+url+'/event/'+eventUrl+'" class="btn color2-bg float-btn">Leer más.<i class="fal fa-angle-right"></i></a>
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but i need keep my URL. In config.url.base_url i´m getting my actual URL i need only add "event/"+eventUrl. but always returned 404

Comment: are you getting your desired url in your href attribute ? and which laravel version are you using ? if you are using 8 you need to update route
In laravel 8 update your route like this :

use App\Http\Controllers\Web\EventController;


Route::get('country',  [EventController::class, 'showEvent'])->name('show-event');

Answer (score 1):

you can use `route name`

add a name to your route:

```
/** SHOW EVENT INFO */
Route::get('event/{url}', 'Web\EventController@showEvent')->name('MyRouteName');
```

and use the route name in href:

```
<a target="_blank" id="button-event-read" href="{{route('MyRouteName', 'MyParameter')}}" class="btn color2-bg float-btn">Leer más.<i class="fal fa-angle-right"></i></a>
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but my script isn´t in blade, it´s script file out of blade, i don´t know if i can use {{route()}}

Comment: i can´t use your solution, i have error in javascript because i can´t use {{route()}} also i need config.url.base_url to get actual URL. for this, i´m traying to concatenate